# Can't import AutoComplete in material UI@next

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to import AutoComplete in Material-UI latest version V1.0.0-beta.26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the [Autocomplete demo](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/autocomplete/) in the [documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/).

With v1, Autocomplete is no longer offered as a core component and can be implemented with [react-autosuggest](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest) ([demo](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/autocomplete/#react-autosuggest)) or [downshift](https://github.com/paypal/downshift) ([demo](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/autocomplete/#downshift)).

Comment: Oh yeah! got it. Thanks. The latest documentation renamed most of the components and got confused :)

Comment: Any specific reason for not including this component in v1? I'm using it from v0 and it seems to work fine with some minor glitches. I'm just concerned about the reliability as it may ruin the whole user experience if there are some serious concerns over using it that I'm unaware of.

Comment: There were ways to achieve this functionality without owning the issues that were being logged.  That’s why.